# Cannot import 'Enum' from 'discord'

Tags: python, importerror

So, I was following a tutorial for a music bot obviously trying to learn how to make specifically a music bot. They were using WaveLink, so I installed WaveLink but when I ran the bot, I got the error `Exception has occurred: ImportError cannot import name 'Enum' from 'discord' (unknown location)`

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Not without seeing your source code.  Did you call your own file "discord.py"?

Comment: No. I named the file "SerialMod.py" and the cog that it's in is called "Music.py" @timroberts

Comment: Alr fixed it lol.